# Regular Expression for decimal numbers

Tags: .net, regex, decimal

I need a validation RegEx for decimal. It should allow up to 5 digits after decimal. Allow:

```
1    
1.0    
12.0    
12.01    
123.01    
1,123.01    
1,123.013
21,123.01234    
3,21,123.01234
```

How Can I do regex for this?

Comment: Do you want to allow the strings "1." or negative numbers? Also, "3,21,123.01234" seems really weird to be used - are you sure you want that to validate?

Comment: @Andrei: it's valid in the Indian numbering system: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system

Comment: Ah, interesting. Learn something new every day. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^[\d,]+(\.\d{1,5})?$
```

Comment: @BipedalSharkYou're right, I am still confused about the use of the coma in general because of the test cases.

Answer (score 4):

http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=decimal

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to validate the positions of the commas?  If so, this works for the Indian numbering system that you seem to be using:

```
^(?:\d{1,2},(?:\d{2},)*\d{3}|\d{1,3})(\.\d{1,5})?$
```

If you want to permit commas in the integer portion but don't care about their positions (except that it can't start or end with a comma), this will do:

```
^\d+(?:,\d+)*(\.\d{1,5})?$
```

Answer (score 0):

**There an excellent library of commonly used regular expressions at http://regexlib.com/.**

You an use a standard expression like: `^\$[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?$` or one of the alternative versions that do much the same thing, depending on the exact flavor you want to match.