# Regular Expression that includes plus sign and decimal

Tags: regex

I'm having trouble putting together a regular expression for a string that contains a number between 0 and 99999, followed by a plus sign, followed by one or two digits, optionally followed by a decimal and a single digit.  For instance:

```
99999+99.9
```

This would also be valid:

```
0+00
```

This would also be valid:

```
0+02.5
```

This would also be valid:

```
0+2.5
```

I found this topic: [How can I check for a plus sign using regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582127/how-can-i-check-for-a-plus-sign-using-regular-expressions)

And this one: 
[Regular Expression for decimal numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775874/regular-expression-for-decimal-numbers)

But am unable to put the 2 together and fulfill the other requirements listed above.

Any help you can provide is much appreciated!

Comment: Would a zero-padded number like `000+12.5` be valid?

Comment: Yes, zero-padded is okay

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
\d{1,5}\+\d{1,2}(?:\.\d)?
```

1. `\d{1,5}` captures anything between 0 and 99999 but also allows zero padding, e.g. `00000` or `00123` (it'll be a little more complicated if you don't want zero padding).
2. `\+` matches a plus sign.
3. `\d{1,2}` matches one or two digits.
4. `(?:\.\d)` matches a period followed by a single digit. The `(?:)` bit indicates a non-capture group.
5. The `?` at the end makes the non-capture group optional.

Comment: The only problem with this is it allows non-numeric characters as well. (i.e. 99b99+99.9 should not be valid because of "b").

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
"^[0-9]*([0-9]{0,5}\+[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9])?)[0-9]*$"
```

EDIT: as per you comment, I have modified the expression.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my question. Non-numeric characters should not be valid.

Comment: The solution you proposed prevents non-numeric characters - however, it allows more than 5 characters to the left of the plus sign. Any way to enforce a max of 5 characters to the left of the plus sign?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't enforce 5 characters to the left of plus sign, 2 characters to the right of plus sign, or 2 characters to the right of decimal (if decimal was supplied).

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the plus and the . -- like so

```
\d{1,5}\+\d{1,2}\.?\d
```

Hth!