# oracle phone number format reg exp in wrong data

Tags: oracle, phone-number, regexp-substr

I come here after checking this topic:
[Regular Expression that includes plus sign and decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446153/regular-expression-that-includes-plus-sign-and-decimal/36768281#36768281)

my main problem is the following, I have wrong migrated data that needs fixing.
for phone numbers we have some letters and special chars that need to be removed.

imagine for example this would be the data:

```
s#sdads+#09232342a
```

I want to get only the + and the numbers
The + must be optional.

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_substr.php
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm

if I read the documentation from oracle this should be quite easy but I can't make it work, I must be missing something basic.
any idea?

below what some examples of what I've tried:

```
select regexp_substr('s#sdads+#09232342a','\+*[0-9]+') from dual;
```

returns

```
09232342
```

I was expecting it to consider the +
I also tried putting the + in the beginning of the test string and no difference.
The same for changing the regexp to

```
[\+]*[0-9]+  or [+]*[0-9]+ or (\+)*(\d)+
```

and there was no difference in the result.

the part that gets me confused is that if I change the test string and the regexp this returns + and only plus

```
select regexp_substr('+s#sdads+#09232342a','?[\+]*') from dual;
```

but if I move the + out of the beginning is gone

also if I put the numbers there, only the numbers are considered:

```
select regexp_substr('+s#sdads+#09232342a','?[\+]*(\d)+') from dual;
```

this also didn't work:

```
select regexp_substr('+s#sdads+#09232342a','?[\+]{0,1}(\d)+') from dual;
```

Comment: it has been fixed, thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `#` character between the `+` and the digits that you need to account for:

**Query 1 - Replace all non-desired characters**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( '+s#sdads+#09232342a', '[^+0-9]' )
FROM   DUAL
```

**Output**:

```
++09232342
```

**Query 2 - Match the entire string**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( '+s#sdads+#09232342a', '^.*?(\+?)#(\d+).*$', '\1\2' )
FROM   DUAL
```

**Output**:

```
+09232342
```

**Query 3 - Match the sub-string**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( '+s#sdads+#09232342a', '\+?#\d+' )
FROM   DUAL
```

*(You could then replace the extraneous `#` by wrapping that statement in another replace)*

**Output**:

```
+#09232342
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in all your tries, you are looking for + followed IMMEDIATELY by digits. Something like this should work:

```
select regexp_substr('+s#sdads+#09232342a', '\+') || 
       regexp_substr('+s#sdads+#09232342a', '\d+') from dual;
```